# Spring Boot 1.4 Testing

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-test-mvc

I'm new to Spring Boot 1.4 testing and trying to put in use the new features. I have a simple Spring MVC controller.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  String index(){
    return "index";
  }
}
```

The controller is returning a Thymeleaf template with  containing the string Hello

I have written the following unit test and it's running fine:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(IndexController.class)
public class SpringMvcTestApplicationTests {


private MockMvc mockMvc;
@Before
public void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new  IndexController()).build();
}

@Test
public void testIndex() throws Exception{

    MvcResult result= this.mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("index"))
            .andReturn();
    String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    assertNotNull(content);
  }
}
```

But I read ***Many of the annotations provide additional auto-configuration that’s specific to testing. For example, if you use @WebMvcTest you can @Autowire a fully configured MockMvc instance.***. I have also seen examples autowiring MockMvc.

But when I add the autowiring code below after removing the @Before method, the test fails.

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

The assertion error is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :401
```

The second issue is, I want to test the content that Thymeleaf returns. I tested with:

```
.andExpect(content().string("Hello"))
```

also

```
.andExpect(content().string(Matchers.containsString("Hello")))
```

and also

```
assertEquals("Hello", content);
```

On examining, I found that content is an empty string, and so the test fails with:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Hello
Actual   :
```

How can I test the content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue:

The problem with using @WebMvcTest to autowire your MockMvc is that it seems to have enabled security by default (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html), which is resulting in your 401 Unauthorized status code for the assertion because the GET request for "/" is failing security checks. For your simple case, it's probably easiest to just stick with using the 'MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup()' to create your MockMvc.

You can add a one liner annotation (be sure to import the package also) to prevent the MockMvc security by doing:

```
@WebMvcTest(IndexController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)
public class IndexControllerTest {
```

Comment: You are right it's due it's due to security issue.  I'm specifically looking how to autowire MockMvc with WebMvcTest annotation. Several articles shows it, but I don't have access to the source code. Few examples are [Official version here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4)  (Testing the Spring MVC slice), [here](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2016/04/17/8-new-features-youll-get-with-spring-boot-1-4/) , [and also here](http://moodle2.insa-lyon.fr/pluginfile.php/73540/mod_resource/content/2/spring-boot-lab.html#testing-mockmvc)

Comment: The issue remains. I have posted the code on GitHub [Click here] (https://github.com/ximanta/blog-spring-mvc-test)

Comment: Got it, also seeing the same issue, so it's not as straightforward as I figured. Scrap that security config, you can modify the default auto configuration of MockMvc with the one liner annotation I posted in my last edit. This permits the IndexControllerTest to pass for me now.

Comment: You dont need `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)`, you can just use `@WebMvcTest(controllers = IndexController.class, secure = false)`

Comment: Both `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)` works fine for `mockMvc.perform(get("/"))`. But for a different URL, say `mockMvc.perform(get("/products"))` or `mockMvc.perform(get("product/{id}", 1))` a `Status` assertion error occurs in  
 `.andExpect(status().isOk())`. What might be the reason?

Comment: Adding to the comment above, the assertion error occurs due to 401 Unauthorized status code being returned instead of the expected 200.